# Setting defaults for number_format in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig

The [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) describes how to set the default parameters for the `number_format` extension. How can I set this in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony2 does not give access to core extension of twig. You can create a `kernel.request` event listener, inject `twig` service and in `onKernelRequest` method of the listener you have to add

```
$this->twig->getExtension('core')->setNumberFormat(3, ',', '.');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Symfony 2.7, through Symfony 4.2-dev I'm running on, **this can now be configured**.

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    number_format:
        decimals: 3
        decimal_point: ','
        thousands_separator: '.'
```

See Symfony blog post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-default-date-and-number-format-configuration